# want to store dataset.info() result into a dataframe in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have created one dataframe in Python and using info() function to see its metadata. But not able to store info() result into dataframe, is there any way to do it.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame ({'A': pd.Series(range(1,4)), 
                    'B' : pd.Timestamp('20181017'),
                    'C' : pd.Series(1, index=list(range(4)), dtype = 'float32'),
                    'D' : np.array([3] * 4, dtype = 'int32'),
                    'E' : pd.Categorical(["test", "train", "test", "train"]),
                    'F' : 'foo'})
df2.info()  #want its output in dataframe.
a = pd.DataFrame(df2.info())
a
```

''''

Answer (score 3):

IIUC:

```
buffer = pd.compat.StringIO()
df2.info(buf=buffer)
s = buffer.getvalue()
df=pd.DataFrame(s.split("\n"),columns=['info'])
print(df)

                                                info
0               <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
1                       Int64Index: 4 entries, 0 to 3
2                     Data columns (total 6 columns):
3                             A    3 non-null float64
4                      B    4 non-null datetime64[ns]
5                             C    4 non-null float32
6                               D    4 non-null int32
7                            E    4 non-null category
8                              F    4 non-null object
9   dtypes: category(1), datetime64[ns](1), float3...
10                         memory usage: 260.0+ bytes
```

You can always slice and modify as you like , once you have the data frame, example :

```
df_info=df.loc[3:8,'info'].str.split(n=1,expand=True).reset_index(drop=True)
print(df_info)

   0                          1
0  A         3 non-null float64
1  B  4 non-null datetime64[ns]
2  C         4 non-null float32
3  D           4 non-null int32
4  E        4 non-null category
5  F          4 non-null object
```

Comment: @jezrael, so no need of importing StringIO from io when using `pd.compat()` ??

Comment: @jezrael Thanks didnt know that, have been importing all this while. :p Thanks for upvoting

Comment: Sure, I have feeling there is some better solution like me :)

Answer (score 0):

An other possibility is with :

```
from io import StringIO
buffer = StringIO()
```

With the Pandas v 1.4.2, I get `AttributeError: module 'pandas.compat' has no attribute 'StringIO'`.