# Pandas.DataFrame.info on html using flask

Tags: python, pandas, flask

I got a question. Is there any way to insert ouutput from this code:

```
>>> import io
>>> buf = io.StringIO()
>>> df.info(buf=buf)
>>> s = buf.getvalue()
>>> type(s)
<class 'str'>
>>> print(s)
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 5 entries, 0 to 4
Data columns (total 2 columns):
a    5 non-null float64
b    5 non-null float64
dtypes: float64(2)
memory usage: 160.0 bytes
```

to html template?
I mean i want information about file shown on template, while i load csv file from my server?
In html it always returning me None.
Is there possibility? Im making flask project

Comment: you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54436095/want-to-store-dataset-info-result-into-a-dataframe-in-python/54436293#54436293

Comment: No, i got a output of csv. But only in my terminal. I want to show it on my html page

Comment: df.info returns a view, not an actual df, so you cant export, cant you create a df like the above link and export to_html?

Comment: Hmmm. I dont know it will be good idea. Its like this:
1) I upload csv to my server
2) I chose file from server
3) I want to get info and describe about him
4) Info dont works in html, describe is ok...

How i can export it?